# How can I use materialize css with react offline?

Tags: css, reactjs, materialize

I'm new to react and started to hate it

there are literally **no documents** about how to use CSS frameworks offline with react.

I don't wanna use `npm` or `CDN` all the time because I'm usually offline

Is there any way to add materialize CSS and js to react like a normal project with `link` and `script`

Comment: You're describing basic setups for web development, if you don't have a grasp over how to link libraries online or offline, you shouldn't jump to reactjs directly

Comment: @ZohirSalak i know how to link stuffs but I don't know how to do it with react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can install the assets of materialize from the offical site
https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html
then you can add the files into public folder after that add the following scripts at public/index.html file like that:-

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
</head>           
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

but this isn't the best practice for react projects.

Comment: Thank you  what do you think about CRAO instead of create react app which is online

Comment: thanks 
sorry, what do you mean by CRAO?

Comment: create react app offline , it has github too

Comment: sorry, i didn't use this tool before